# Sufficient conditions for super-exponential growth

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1,2,... \}$.

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function which satisfies:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{f(n)} = 0$$

for every $k > 0$. Then, for each $k$, there exists:

$$N(k) := \min \{ N : \forall n \ge N, \frac{n^k}{f(n)} < 1 \}$$

Which conditions on the increasing sequence $N(k)$ ensure that $f$ grows at least exponentially i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r^n}{f(n)} = 0 $$

for some $r>1$?

I am not entirely sure how to approach this problem. It is easy to check that $N(k) = k$ is sufficient, but $N(k) = k^m$ (for $m>1$) or $2^k$ is not, and I wonder if exponential growth as described is equivalent to the convergence of some series related to $N(k)$.

The sequence $(N(k))$ is my own idea; I would also interested in other criteria which do not relate to it. It may also be convenient to assume $f$ extends to an analytic map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This can then be rephrased as a question about the Taylor expansion of $f$ conjugated with $ x \mapsto x^{-1}$.

Comment: $k\log k$ is also sufficient, but $k\log^{1+\delta}k$ is not sufficient.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is $N(k) \le c k \log k$ where we can take $c$ roughly $1/\log r$ and viceversa $r=e^{1/c}$ again roughly

Comment: the above actually is better put as $\limsup N(k)/(k \log k)=c < \infty$ Then $c,r$ are in the relation mentioned; so if the limit is zero, then we can take any $r>1$ for example

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Intriguing, because that is consistent with the series convergence test I was tacitly describing, $\sum N(k)^{-1} < \infty$.

Comment: @Conrad Would you like to write an answer which I could accept? I will work on it myself if not in some time, but I may need to ask for help. I am curious how you derived it.

Comment: put a solution that while has technical details (to get the best $r, \limsup$ relation, boils down to the fact that the equation (in $n,k$ for fixed $r>1$ say)  $r^n=n^k$ has as approximate solution $n=k \log k/ \log r$ or equivalently $k=n \log r/(\log n)$ with the rest being just standard manipualtions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, let's show that the necessary and sufficient condition is $\limsup \frac{N(k)}{k \log k}=c < \infty$ and we will get estimates for $c$ in terms of $r$ and vice versa in the process; in particular, we can take arbitrary $r>1$ iff $c=0$

Let's assume first $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r^n}{f(n)} = 0$ for some $r>1$ and note that this implies that $f(n)>r^n, n >n_0$.

Now for $k$ large, let's see when $r^n > n^k$ (and $n >n_0$) as that clearly means that $N(k)\le n$ as $f(n)>r^n>n^k$ then by our choices; taking logarithms we need $n \log r > k \log n$ and we notice that if $a >1$ and $n > a\frac{k \log k}{\log r}$ eg $n=[a\frac{k \log k}{\log r}]+1$ we have $n \log r/\log n> a\frac{k \log k}{\log k +\log \log k}>k$  for $k>k(a)$.

So for all such $k>k(a)$ if $n > a\frac{k \log k}{\log r}$ we have $N(k) \le n$ (as long as also $a\frac{k \log k}{\log r}>n_0$ which we can clearly get by increasing $k(a)$ if needed)

Hence $N(k) \le a\frac{k \log k}{\log r}+1, k>k(a)$ or $\limsup \frac{N(k)}{k \log k} \le \frac{a}{\log r}$ hence since $a >1$ arbitrary we get $$\limsup \frac{N(k)}{k \log k} \le \frac{1}{\log r}$$

In particular if we can take arbitrary large $r$ and still have $r^n/f(n) \to 0$ we get $\lim \frac{N(k)}{k \log k} =0$

Let's now assume conversely that $\limsup \frac{N(k)}{k \log k} \le c < \infty$ and wlog assume $c>0$ and let's take $a>1$ so there is $k(a)$ st $\frac{N(k)}{k \log k} <ac, k>k(a)$.

Pick now $n$ large enough st $ n/(ac \log n) >k(a)$ and note that with $k(a)< k \le n/(ac \log n)$ we have $k \log k \le (n/(ac \log n))(\log n -\log (ac \log n))<\frac{n}{ac}$.

But this means that for all such $n$ large enough if we take $k=[n/(ac \log n)]$ we have by the above $ac k \log k <n$ or $N(k) <n$ or $$f(n)>n^k>n^{n/(ac \log n)-1}=\frac{b^n}{n}, b=e^{1/ac}$$

But this means that for any $1<b_1<b$ eg for $b_1 =e^{1/(a^2c)}$ we have $f(n)/b_1^n \to \infty$ so one can take $r=e^{1/(a^2c)}$ but $a>1$ arbitrary so one can take as $r$ any $e^{1/c_1}$ with $c_1>c$.

In particular, if  $\lim \frac{N(k)}{k \log k} =0$, we can take in the above arbitrary $c>0$ hence arbitrary $c_1>0$ hence arbitrary $r>1$ as claimed.

Comment: I am still reading, and this is impressive, but I have a question. I agree that $n > \frac{a k \log k}{\log r}$ is sufficient for $r^n > n^k$. What about the additional condition that $n > n_0$ for $f(n) > r^n$, which is what you use to deduce the behaviour of $N(k)$? I may have misunderstood, but what if $\frac{a k \log k}{\log r} < n_0$? Edit: I think I have a similar question for the second part.

Comment: since we deal with $k \to \infty$ and $n_0$ is just a constant depending on $r$, we just take $k$ large enough so $\frac{a k \log k}{\log r} > n_0$ (eg we increase $k(a)$ in the terminology) - that's why the correct parameter is $\limsup_{k \to \infty}\frac{N(k)}{k \log k}$ and not $\sup \frac{N(k)}{k \log k}, k \ge 2$

Comment: I see; thank you. Also, I see you already wrote this in the answer and I missed it, so apologies.

Comment: no problem - took a bit to write it carefully, but the idea is not that complicated as noted - and natural from the theory of power series where this type of estimate (estimating integral solutions to equations of the type $r^n=n^k$) is common